# PowerBI - using the results of already existing visuals for further analysis

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Let's say I have two matrix objects on a PowerBI canvas, manipulated *separately* by 2 different slicers as indicated below:
[image]

My question is: is it possible to create a third object (matrix, table, whatever) that shows us the difference between the two previously shown matrix values by message type. I was thinking of a solution something like this:
[image]

Is it possible to achieve such solution in PowerBI?

Comment: It should be possible if you use two distinct date tables. Pretty sure you can't do it with just one.